# On button click navigate to a tab screen

Tags: flutter

I am using a tab controller in flutter, but how do i able to navigate to a certain tab screen with a button click. I put my tab controller in my main screen then 3 different screens. Below is my example codes.

**Main Screen (with tab controller)**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

int _currentIndex = 0;
TabController _tabController;
final List<Widget> _children = [
firstscreen.FirstScreen(),
secondscreen.SecondScreen(),
thirdscreen.ThirdScreen()
];

List<Widget> _tabs = <Widget>[
Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), text: 'Home'),
Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.history), text: 'History'),
Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), text: 'Profile'),
];

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_tabController = TabController(length: _tabs.length, vsync: this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
_tabController.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: _onWillPop,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("My Title"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Data Screen()));
          },
        ),
      ],
      bottom: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: _tabs,
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: _children,
    ),
  ),
);
}

void onTabTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _currentIndex = index;
});
}
```

**First Screen**

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
FirstScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
@override
FirstScreenState createState() {
return new FirstScreenState();
}
}

class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen>
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<FirstScreen> {

Widget get historyCard {
return Container(
  height: 280,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
  child: Card(
    elevation: 4.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ClipPath(
          clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            left: 10,
            child: Text("RECENT ACTIVITY",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                )),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('MORE >'),
              onPressed: () => {},
              textColor: Colors.blueAccent, // JUMP TO SECOND TAB or ANY 
//OTHER TAB
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(children: [
    historyCard,
  ]),  
);
}
}
```

So right now i'm not sure how do i able to navigate to any tab with button click, because i place my tab bar in `MainScreen.dart`or must i change the `FirstPage` code into the `MainScreen.dart`, then only can click and navigate?

Comment: I don't know if it'll be overkill or not but you can try to use Stream. Send the current index to the stream, on the MainScreen listen that stream. Change the tab index whenever new index arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set index in TabController to change current tab as below:
In below example, one button is in TabBarView screen in "MyFirstTab", from that button press we call the changeMyTab() of parent class which is "StateKeeper".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTabController extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return StateKeeper();
  }
}

class StateKeeper extends State<MyTabController> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController;
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),),
    new Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),),
    new Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat),),
    new Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_railway),),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);

  }

  changeMyTab(){
    setState(() {
      _tabController.index = 2;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(

        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: myTabs, controller: _tabController,),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),

          body: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
            MyFirstTab(onTabChangeCallback: () => {
                changeMyTab()
            },),
            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
            Icon(Icons.directions_railway),
          ]),

        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyFirstTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFirstTab({this.onTabChangeCallback});
  final TabChangeCallback onTabChangeCallback;

  createState() {
    return MyFirstTabStateKeeper(onTabChangeCallback);
  }
}

class MyFirstTabStateKeeper extends State<MyFirstTab> {

  TabChangeCallback onTabChangeCallback;

  MyFirstTabStateKeeper(TabChangeCallback onTabChangeCallback){
    this.onTabChangeCallback = onTabChangeCallback;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Change Tab'),
          onPressed: onTabChangeCallback,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

typedef TabChangeCallback = void Function();
```